# How get signature form message forms on Netherum

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, signature, ether

Tell me how to get a message type signature on C# Netherum

[image][image]
For regular messages I do this, but it's no different. Here's what I usually use

```
                string privateKeyHex = "72d09fdace341e58728b83eb18a97dfefe2b2ed64d04743630f6d69df63af658";
                string originalText = @"textMessage";
                string messageToSign = originalText.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
                //Signature
                var key = new EthECKey(privateKeyHex);
                var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
                string signature = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign(messageToSign, key);
                return signature;`
```

in the request that is sent there is a date of the form, as far as I understand, the first part is ABI, but I just can’t understand how to form it

"data": {
"domain": {
"name": "snapshot",
"version": "0.1.4"
},
"types": {
"Vote": [{
"name": "from",
"type": "address"
}, {
"name": "space",
"type": "string"
}, {
"name": "timestamp",
"type": "uint64"
}, {
"name": "proposal",
"type": "bytes32"
}, {
"name": "choice",
"type": "uint32"
}, {
"name": "reason",
"type": "string"
}, {
"name": "app",
"type": "string"
}, {
"name": "metadata",
"type": "string"
}
]
},
"message": {
"space": "servise.eth",
"proposal": "0xcd749b3b1caea7f5f2ecc3d1270eb2f938819f015d4410e5e07f77cab47e9ec9",
"choice": 2,
"app": "appVote",
"reason": "",
"metadata": "{}",
"from": "0x8A652fd68C4702AB7Eeba24e21611c2B81dc4596",
"timestamp": 1695386652
}
}

Comment: To understand, these are ordinary voting on SnapShot, you can go to any spaces and vote where there is one answer
Example https://snapshot.org/#/pistachiodao.eth/proposal/0x38c654c0f81b63ea1839ec3b221fad6ecba474aa0c4e8b4e8bc957f70100e753

Comment: I read that the data needs to be signed using Nethereum.ABI.EIP712, but I don’t know how to do it